# What is the Oath in Court

Tags: sentence

I see that in Court, before witness says anything, he will say something like this “in the name of god, what I say is true and correct”. Is there a standard version of this oath?

Thanks

Comment: add your research to your question if you please.

Comment: This seems like more of a law question than an English question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolute standard among countries or even within countries.

In UK courts there is an **oath** and there is an **affirmation**.

> An affirmation has exactly the same legal effect as an oath but is usually taken to avoid the religious implications of an oath; it is thus legally binding but not considered a religious oath.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmation_in_law)

The situation is similar in the USA :

> The original 1787 text of the Constitution of the United States makes three references to an "**oath or affirmation**":

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmation_in_law)

Answer (score 0):

It  varies according to the country:

> [Sworn testimony](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sworn_testimony) is evidence given by a witness who has made a commitment to tell the truth. If the witness is later found to have lied whilst bound by the commitment, they can often be charged with the crime of perjury. The types of commitment can include oaths, affirmations and promises which are explained in more detail below. ***The exact wording of the commitments vary from country to country.***

From instance in Australia:

> I swear (or the person taking the oath may promise) by Almighty God (or the person may name a god recognised by his or her religion) that the evidence I shall give will be the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth.

In the UK:

> I swear by [substitute Almighty God/Name of God (such as Jehovah) or the name of the holy scripture] that the evidence I shall give shall be the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth.

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 0):

The words used do not matter at all. The point is that the witness states formally that he or she asserts that the evidence to be given is true. If it turns out that that was a lie, then, whatever the formal words, that witness is in trouble.

The actual words required vary from country to country but their import is the same, and they are intended to cause witnesses to think hard before they tell lies.